# Can one use .wls (script) files in a simple way, like Matlab scripts?

Tags: packages

I have been fighting unsucessfully with the intricacies of creating Mathematica packages
(Private,  scopes , context)  for a long time.
 I just need a simple version of Matlab scripts, to be able 
to hide from my esyes  some 50 lines  in a different file, (so I do not  see them all day).

So, I created in the same directory a file called AUXILIARY.wls

```
WI=(Integrate[W[x],{x,0,#}])&;
Z=(1+q  WI[#])&
```

AND CALLED it as suggested in the guide ref/Get << EquationTrekker`

```
<< AUXILIARY'
Names["AUXILIARY'*"]
```

This failed `Get::noopen: Cannot open AUXILIARY.` 
So, is there a simple way a file can use definitions in another?  Thanks

Comment: You need to evaluate `Get["AUXILIARY.wls"]` instead (assuming you had placed the relevant file in one of the directories listed in `$Path`); ``<< AUXILIARY`​`` only works if you had used things like `BeginPackage[]`/`EndPackage[]` from within `AUXILIARY.wls`.

Comment: Also it's a back-tick at the end, not a single quote: ``AUXILIARY` ``, not `AUXILIARY'`

Comment: Thanks! One more (unrelated) problem.  WI=(Integrate[W[x],{x,0,#}])&;WI[0]  works correctly, but leads to error message General::ivar: 0 is not a valid variable. If I use instead of the pure function WI[z_]:=(Integrate[W[x],{x,0,y}])/.y->z; WI[0] the error message disapears. What's wrong with my using a  pure function?

Comment: I don't get any error. It normally means that the variable, which is `x` in this case, has a value, i.e., `0` in error you report.  `Clear[x]` would fix it, or restarting the kernel.  A better def. is `WI = Block[{x}, Integrate[W[x], {x, 0, #}]] &` which temporarily localizes and clears `x`; even better is to use `Module` instead of `Block`; then the local variable `x` would be different than the `x` in a call like `WI[x]`.

Comment: It must be something to do with my ambition to use a .wls script instead of learning packages, since the error appeared after moving these definitions in a different file. I tried Module, but now I get an additional error Module::lvsym: Local variable specification {#1} contains #1, which is not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol besides the old one

Comment: Still wrong. I changed the script to a package (defining WI by Module). I define W in the main file W = InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(s + 2), s, #] &;
W[x]
Get["Auxi.wl"]; Then I call WI[1] FullSimplify[WI[1] //. cnn] Besides old  error 0 is not..., a new strange message \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), 
FractionBox[\(1\), \(4\)]]\(Auxi`Private`W[
   Auxi`Private`x$45229] \[DifferentialD]Auxi`Private`x$45229\)\)

Comment: New problem. The integration limit  in the weird message for WI[1]  is changed from 1 to 1/4!!! This problem disappears for FullSimplify[WI[x] //. cnn /. x -> 1], and does not appear for other limits different from 1.  Packages are hard to comprehend :)

Comment: I solved the problem, it came from a condition W[0] -> 1/c which is logically upsetting, since W is defined in a different way. Sorry  :)